# raw-loader for compiled Typescript files in Webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm using Webpack with Typescript and making a script. Part of the job of this script is to manipulate the DOM of a contained iframe, and add a script into that iframe. I would like to use webpack and typescript for both the main script and the script to inject.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
import fileAsString from "!someLoader!inject.ts";

const doc=document.querySelector("iframe").contentDocument; // It's same-origin so no problems here

const script=doc.createElement("script");
script.textContent=fileAsString;
doc.appendChild(script);
```

I would prefer to have this all compile to one file (so no making a separate entrypoint and setting the `src` of the script to that).

Is there any convenient way to do this in Webpack? I'm familiar with the `raw-loader` but I haven't seen any functionality there besides just reading from the source file (as opposed to the compiled version).

I was thinking that there might be a way to do two entrypoints and have the main script load the contents of the second entrypoint, but I don't know how to do this or even if it is supported.